# how do i write the drive to go through in windows batch script that goes through each folder in the drive and tells me how many files are in each

Tags: windows, batch-file

I wrote this batch script so that it can go through each folder and tell me how many files in this folder but I only want it to apply to a certain drive how would I write this?`do I add it right after @echo off? also how do you write the path for the drive (i.e. if my drive is name lets say "adrive" under the Y: how would I write it if that makes sense)

```
@echo off
title File Counter batch.
:recurse
set I=1

echo "files in folder"
cd
REM view all files, EXCEPT directories.
FOR /f "tokens=*" %%P IN ('dir /A-d /b') do (call :showfiles "%%P")
echo Filecount: %I%
REM now call on all subfolders...



pause
:showfiles
echo %1
set /a I+=1
goto :eof`
```

Comment: You'll need `goto :EOF` before `:showfiles` in order not to unintentionally fall into that code section again…

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to know how many files are in each folder of a certain drive. That's quite easy: `for /d /r` lists you recursively each folder. Use a second `for /f` loop to count the files for each folder:

```
@echo off   
setlocal
set sum=0
for /d /r "Y:\" %%a in (*) do (
  for /f %%b in ('dir /b /a-d "%%a\*" 2^>nul ^|find /c /v ""') do (
    echo %%b    %%a
    set /a sum+=%%b
  )
)
echo sum=%sum%
```

NOTE: this counts non-hidden, non-system files only. Adapt the `dir` switches to change that when needed.